# JPA query to work with daterange of postgresql

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Actual DB table:

```
 Column |   Type    | Collation | Nullable | Default
--------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------
 room   | text      |           |          |
 during | daterange |           |          |
```

Working DB query:

```
select * from room_reservation where during && daterange('[2020-10-15,2020-11-14)');
```

Entity Mapping:

```
@Column(name = "during", columnDefinition = "daterange")
private Range<Date> during;
```

Jpa Repository:

```
@Query(value = "select r.room from Room_Occupancy r where r.during && daterange('[?1, ?2)')", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Long> findOccupiedRooms(@Param("d1") Date d1, @Param("d2") Date d2);
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: "?1"
  Position: 65
```

How can I write same query in JPA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @Query(value = "select r.room from Room_Occupancy r where r.during && daterange(''||'[' || :d1 ||',' || :d2 ||')' || '')", nativeQuery = true)
        List<Long> findOccupiedRooms(@Param("d1") Date d1, @Param("d2") Date d2);
```

This worked

Comment: I don't understand why extra `''` is needed to concat on both side. I tested it's working without it  .

Comment: Can you explain a  bit your solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Here, `'[?1, ?2)'` inside string literal parameter can't be replaced. You can use `||` to concat as string where the parameters can be replaced.

```
@Query(value = "select r.room from Room_Occupancy r where r.during &&"
      + " daterange('[' || :d1 || ',' || :d2 || ')')", nativeQuery = true)
  List<Long> findOccupiedRooms(@Param("d1") Date d1, @Param("d2") Date d2);
```

Answer (score 0):

As it's a native query use ? as parameter placeholders:

```
@Query(value = "select r.room from Room_Occupancy r where r.during && daterange('[?, ?)')", nativeQuery = true)
List<Long> findOccupiedRooms(@Param("d1") Date d1, @Param("d2") Date d2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:-

```
    @Query(value = "select r.room from Room_Occupancy r where r.during >= ?1 and r.during < ?2", nativeQuery = true)
    List<String> findOccupiedRooms(Date d1,Date d2); //d1 < d2
```